# Cohomology/Homology of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am struggling to calculate the homology and cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ wich coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ under it's trivial action (by which I mean the additive group of fractions of the form $a/2^i$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $i\in\mathbb{N}$). Does anybody know of a projective resolution which I could use to solve this?

Comment: The title and the text are different. Do you assume that $p=2$?

Comment: Well in general I am asking for any p but I would be happy with just a result for p=2

Comment: Do you know the topological interpretation of group (co)homology ? If you do, then you can interpret $\mathbb Z[1/p]$ as the $\pi_1$ of  a mapping telescope of an infinite sequence $S^1\to S^1\to ....\to S^1 \to...$ where each map has degree $p$

Comment: I have vague knowledge of the topological interpretation here, what do you mean by the degree of the mapping?